# Trying to refresh import XML xpath query, jquery string changes URL and breaks the request

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have successfully used importxml to pull down data from live NBA games on espn.com. However, I need the importxml function to refresh every minute (or some frequent amount of time) to keep fetching the live data and have it update in my google sheets.

I found this script online to refresh the import xml but it adds a jquery string to the end of the URL for cache busting. The jquery string at the end of the URL changes the URL from being in a specific game like this:
https://www.espn.com/nba/game?gameId=401161051
(which would successfully fetch the data) back to just the NBA scoreboard:
https://www.espn.com/nba/game?gameId=401161051.1234232

I need the import xml function to successfully refresh while cache busting, without adding a random number to the end of the URL because espn sends you to a different page if that happens.

This is my import XML function that works successfully

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.espn.com/nba/matchup?gameId=401161049","//tr[20]")
```

Comment: We need a sample sheet link, your formula returns `imported content is empty` you can't use rand() in import functions so not sure how you even tested random number.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your import formula is in cell A2 you will make the following modification:

```
=IMPORTXML("your link&"&A1,"your xpath")
```

Then in cell A1 do

```
=today()^0+A1
```

Don't forget to enable these settings:

[image]

Congrats it updates every minute and edit.

Comment: I just realized I had the importxml with the jquery string on the end in my original post which doesn't work... I fixed it now and it fetches data correctly if you copy and paste it.  I tried to use your solution and couldn't get it to work with the importxml that I have, it just says loading...

Comment: Your formula is saying `loading...` even without my formula modification. Try it, just remove the parts I edited and you will see it still says `loading...`

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*You can use an Apps Script time-based trigger to go off every minute and update the cell in question.*

#### More Information:

From the `Tools > Script editor` menu item, you can create a function with the following code:

```js
function updateTheSheet() {
  var formula = '=IMPORTXML("https://www.espn.com/nba/matchup?gameId=401161049","//tr[20]")'
  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  ss.getSheets()[0].getRange('A2').setFormula(formula);
}
```

Assuming that the cell you wish to have update is in the first sheet, in cell A2. You can change this in the `getRange()` function.

From here, save the script with the save icon, press the run button (►), and confirm the authentication of running the script.

From here,  following the `Edit > Current project's triggers` menu item, you will have a new page open in the G Suite Developer Hub. Click the `+ Add Trigger` button in the bottom right and set up the trigger settings as follows:

- Choose which function to run: `updateTheSheet`
- Choose which deployment should run: `Head`
- Select event source: `Time-driven`
- Select type of time based trigger: `Minutes timer`
- Select minute interval: `Every minute`

And press save. Now, the function will run each minute and update that cell with the formula, causing the formula to recalculate and update itself.

#### References:

- [Google Apps Script - `setForumla()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setFormula(String))
- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

Comment: I'm not sure if it is google or the website but after changing the formula or making it refresh 3 or 4 times it seems to just get stuck on `Loading...` my solution has the same problem as well.

Comment: yep as codecamper said it updated once for me, then stopped working.  I think it has something to do with the "cache busting" stuff that people talk about online.  The cache busting can be solved by creating a unique URL with the jquery string on the end of the URL (as my original script solution I found online did), but in the case of this specific ESPN link the jquery string changes the URL to a different web page, and therefore the importxml doesn't import the data correctly

Comment: @Kyle [I have had mine running for a long while now updating every minute](https://i.imgur.com/YyUT71P.png) and my Sheet still [displays correctly without the `Loading...` mentioned](https://i.imgur.com/3bjwVRj.png) - are you still experiencing this?